# Python How To Use Pexpect Correctly?

Tags: python, bash

I just started using `pexpect` in order to try to install packages which need a lot of input in order to install. I am trying to install the Homebrew package using Pexpect here.

Here is the command to install homebrew :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

When I type this command in, I first get this prompt : `Password:`
Then, I get the prompt `Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort`.

I have tried to write a script using pexpect to install the scripts.

```
import pexpect as px
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass() #Password as a string from the user
px.run('''/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"''') #Triple quotes because command contains double quotes
px.expect('Password:')
px.send(password)
px.expect('Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort')
px.send('\n')
```

Is this the correct way to automate the installation of this script? Please let me know if this is fine.

Thanks a lot and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: in many programs which gets data from `stdin` (like `keyboard` in console) you can create file with all answers (in separated lines) and run `program < all_answers.txt` but I don't know if it will work with password because it may use special function to hide password

Comment: Is this script which I have written is correct? I have already found a way to get the password hidden. Let me know if this script might work

Comment: just try your script and see if it works.

Comment: first run and if you get error message then show it in question. Don't expect that we will run it - and it may work correctly on our computers but not work on your computer.

Comment: see documentation for [run()](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pexpect/run.html) - it seems it runs code and wait on its finish and you can't use it with `expect` and `send`. You would need `spawn()` to use `expect` and `send`. Or `run(... events={"Password:": password, ...})`

Comment: Yeah, I already ran it before asking the question and had ran it but had found some errors about the input of information, so i had to remove the expect() and just blindly send information instead which worked for some reason